# Why my OR Operator in angularjs is not working?

Tags: angularjs

I am using a if condition in angularjs to check is a status is != Delivered  or status is != Canceled then alert a message

```
    if($scope.itemDeliveredStatus != "Canceled" || $scop.itemDeliveredStatus != "Delivered"))
{
    alert("Please set item status to Delivered! or Canceled!");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: consider using jslint or eslint, there are a bunch of typos

Answer (score 1):

Typo on the second condition, you put `$scop` instead of `$scope` :

```
$scop.itemDeliveredStatus
```

and an extra `)` at the end of that line which is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

First you do have a typo, but that is only one small issue. The other is a logic problem.

Your logic is wrong with the use of OR. Simple example below shows you that.

```js
var foo = "A";
if (foo !== "A" || foo !== "B") {
  console.log("WHY?")
}
```

Why? Because you are saying that in order for this if statement to be true, the variable foo has to be equal to two things.

You want it to say if foo does not equal A AND foo does not equal B, than show error.

```js
var foo = "A";
if (foo !== "A" && foo !== "B") {
  console.log("WHY?")
} else {
  console.log("Better!!!")
}
```

So with the two issues fixed, your code would look like:

```
if ($scope.itemDeliveredStatus != "Canceled" && $scope.itemDeliveredStatus != "Delivered") { /*.. code */ }
```